# Python 3 OS walk unicode exception

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using python 3.3.3 in win7 - I just want to list all the files in a network directory.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("X:\\network\\path\\foo\\bar\\baz"):
    print(root)
    print(dirs)
    print(files)
```

After a while of printing stuff it outputs this exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(files)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position
2753: character maps to <undefined>
```

How do I get this to print simply?  I always seem to have these unicode problems with python 3.  I just want simple things be simple.

Comment: You're trying to print a character to a console that is incapable of printing that specific character. What should Python do?

Comment: IDK - Escape with the \u2019 in the position?  Just not puke?  Why does it work in python 2 (tried and it works)

Comment: It works because Python 2 doesn't convert filenames to Unicode automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7, the console doesn't properly support Unicode encodings. You need to encode your strings to cp-437:

```
print(root.encode("cp437", "backslashreplace").decode("cp437"))
```

That should remove all the characters unprintable in the DOS console and replace them with their `\unnnn` or `\xnn` equivalent.

Comment: @MKaras: If you open the file using a Unicode-aware encoding (`with open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as output: output.write(root)`), then yes.